# If an object is pushed on a frictionless surface would it have a constant velocity or acceleration after say 5minutes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces

I have a doubt in this question I think that the answer would be constant acceleration but please help me out

Comment: Have you heard of Newton's Laws? What do they say? Since you put the tag "Forces" on your question, I'm guessing you do.

Comment: I do but i still I have a doubt in the question idk why could you help me out please

Comment: I don't know what your specific question is that would go beyond what Newton's Laws say. Are you confused about what they say?

Comment: No no my question is let’s suppose there is a ball of mass m which is on a frictionless furnace and it is pushed by a force F now after any time period would it be in accelerated motion or travel with a constant velocity

Comment: Now that I think about it , it should accelerate for the time period of the force then it should be move with a constant velocity .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now that I think about it , it should accelerate for the time period of the force then it should be move with a constant velocity.

Exactly , this is what Newton's first law predicts. **Only a force can  change the state of rest or constant velocity**. *And the change is only till the force acts*, if the force stops acting , the change of velocity stops too. So after the force is removed , it moves with constant velocity all along the path.

Hope it helps .

Answer (score 2):

If your object is subject to a net force, it accelerates.  If not, the velocity is constant.